# Need to Find A JQuery solution similar to app for Ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had a meeting with our president this morning who was wanting to have our team page function similar to the following app for her Ipad:
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/appstream-for-ipad/id375288393?mt=8

There is a lot of movement and I am not sure where to really begin.  In our case the thumbnails would be pictures of our people and when you clicked the photo a pop up box with description and contact information would be available for the user.  I am wondering if anyone has seen a JQuery plugin I could use to simulate this affect or something else I could build on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A good place to start: http://jquerymobile.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone that is interested, here is what I wound up doing.

I used a JQuery plugin called "quicksand" for the animation part of it, then set up some an AJAX request on a timer to call a php page with a list of all employees in random order.  Give a similar effect to what we were looking for, thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

One way i could think is to just have the thubnail images and then load the appropriate profiles in a fancy box

http://fancybox.net/

Or do it all manually, by having a hidden, absolute positioned Overlay and then present it on click

Comment: Thanks for the input, I would probably use something like that for the pop up effect. The effect I am having trouble with making the thumbnails move in a counter clockwise motion.  I don't think the webpage I supplied shows that effect but if you download it on an Ipad all the app images move in counter clockwise motion with the middle app image disappearing and going back to the top right hand corner.

Comment: Its complicated to explain but looks really cool on the Ipad and would work really well to show the diversity of our company.

Comment: so i downloaded the app and i doubt there is a plugin for this specific thing. You can however just keep a list of all the thumbnails and make them move individually, based on their level

Comment: so you are suggesting to move the individual thumbnails on each row as oppose to the swirling motion?  Is there a specific plugin you would recommend?

Comment: what im saying is that there is no plugin for this specific cause. i would just do an animation that moves all the thumbnails individually with absolute positioning